# Django: force content_type ID

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-contenttypes

Each time I rebuild a new database from the same Django project, ContentType IDs are not assured to be the same. This make it difficult to compare data from two DBs.

Is there a way to force an ID for a given ContentType / Model?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a function to `post_migrate` signal which would call Django's fixtures related management commands (`dumpdata` and `loaddata`) accordingly.

In case there is already a json fixture file created on a specific path function code may flush content types automatically added during migration and populate rows from fixture. Otherwise dump just populated rows (`dumpdata`).

**More in docs:**

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-migrate
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code